# How to reach the uncle using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, parents

```
<div id="grandfather">
  <div id="uncle"></div>
  <div id="father>
    <div id="me"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am at $("#me") , and I want to select my uncle, using stuff like :

```
 $("#me").find("#uncle")
 $("#me").next("#uncle")
 $("#me").prev("#uncle")
```

How ?

Comment: This question seems a little too arbitrary for a useful answer. I'd suggest just studying jQuery's [traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) unless you can provide more context.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `$.parent` and `$.prev` assuming your uncle is always above your father:

```
$(this).parent().prev(); // where 'this' is #me
```

You could also go all the way up to your grandfather, and find uncles from there:

```
$(this).parents("#grandfather").find(".uncles");
```

Or you could search your father's siblings:

```
$(this).parent().siblings("#uncle");
```

I would encourage you to read the [Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) portion of the jQuery API for various other methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
var uncle = $('#me').parent().prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().prev().append("This is uncle");
```